conjugate method for minimization of quadratic equations of dim n, upper bound for iterations is n?
Is it true that in the worst case, the conjugate gradient algorithm needs 20 or 21 iterations to converge for the minimization of a quadratic equation of dimension 20? Let's suppose it won't find the minimum before 20 or 21 for this quadratic equation.

In exact arithmetic the cg requires 20 iterations,if the matrix has 20 distinct eigenvalues. You could verify this with a diagonal matrix with 20 distinct values,e.g. in python. Usually preconditioning is used to reduce the number of iterations. For Jacobi (diagonal) preconditioning the nummer of iterations reduces to one for this diagonal matrix (all eigenvalues are equal then).

The $k$-th iteration of conjugate gradient minimizes some residual over a $k$-dimensional subspace so if the system is $n$-dimensional then the maximum number of iterations is $n$ since it is minimizing the residual, and hence solving the system, over the entire space

@whpowell96 thanks, so it is true what I wrote, but wait it can never be 21 iterations if n = 20?

@dweber thanks, I mean, can you refer to any material to check further? Because I am not sure if 21 would be a valid iteration after the 20th.

Due to round-off, you might not achieve convergence after 20 iterations. 21 would not surprise me. The 21th iteration will still be valid.
